# Thread-exclusive data: how to store and access?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there a possibility in .NET to bind an object instance to a current execution context of a thread?
So that in any part of the code I could do something like `CurrentThread.MyObjectData.DoOperation()` and be sure that I access thread-specific data?
thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could take a look at the [ThreadStaticAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx). Another helpful methods are [SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setdata.aspx)/[GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getdata.aspx) which allow you to store data relative to the current thread.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using .NET 4.0, there's now also ThreadLocal<T>:

[System.Threading.ThreadLocal<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(VS.100).aspx)

Nick

Comment: And if your using async there is AsyncLocal ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-5.0