# C# Debugging - How can I tell what created a worker thread?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, threadpool

I am testing a Universal Windows Platform application which has buttons. When I push a sequence of buttons and pause the program after it's done doing work, I see only the Main thread and a worker thread. If I do the same thing fast enough, I will find an additional worker thread which never goes away.

I want to find my mistake which led to this leftover worker thread, but I've been unsuccessful with the debugging tools so far. Threads window only shows ID, Managed ID, Category = Worker Thread, Name = < No Name >, Location = < not available >, Priority = Normal.

How can I find out anything more about this leftover worker thread? E.g., when it was spawned, what it was doing, why it's not destroyed.

Comment: It is just a threadpool thread that is currently not executing any code.  Waiting for work to do, patiently waiting in the pool.  They are always around when you target UWP, lots and lots of async around.  The only problem is that you don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set data in your threads as you create them, and presumably you'll be able to access that data during debugging.  You can use that data store to hold debug information such as where it was created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/creating-threads-and-passing-data-at-start-time

Also there are tips here [Thread-exclusive data: how to store and access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309700/thread-exclusive-data-how-to-store-and-access)

Comment: I'm not sure I can make use of this since thread.start() and similar methods are not available in UWP applications. I am hoping someone can tell me how to know what spawned a worker thread without necessarily modifying the code.